# this is the problem occured to me while installing docker engine using amazon ec2 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, devops

E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update?
Try this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install docker.io -y
```